# Redirecting to another view with @PathVariable missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

I do have problem with redirection in Spring web app.

So, I do have an specificEmployee view. That's the controller method to render the view.

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String showSpecificEmployee(@PathVariable String id, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeById(new Long(id)));
    model.addAttribute("date", new DateCommand());

    return "specificEmployee";
}
```

On the same specificEmployee view there's an input to get a `Date`, so I can filter employee's working hours. And that's why I'm passing new `DateCommand`.

Now the controller method to capture the Date.

```
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/passdate")
public String updateWorkmonth(@ModelAttribute DateCommand dateCommand){

    System.out.println(dateCommand.getActualDate());

    return "redirect:/main";
}
```

Everything's fine, the `Date`  prints correctly, but I would like to stay on the same view, but this time I don't have the `@PathVariable` `id` to pass to the redirect in the second method. The form to get the `Date` looks as follows:

```
<form th:object="${date}" th:action="@{/passdate}">
    Choose a month:
    <input type="month" th:field="*{actualDate}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How to pass the `id` value of the first method to the second method's return statement? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about adding a hidden field with the employees id, which in turn gets then also re-submitted again?

Comment: Thanks. That worked!